# JS length is shorter than number of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS array that has length 20, but .length, a forEach, and a for loop all say basically 11.

Some ways I tried to calc it (began with .length):

```
    console.log('data length: ' + data.length);
    var myLen = 0;
    myLen = Object.keys(data).length;
    console.log( 'myLen: ' + myLen);
    for (var i = 0, len = 0; i < data.length; i++, data[i] !== undefined && len++);
    console.log('real length: ' + len );
```

---

The above code's output:

data length: 11
myLen: 11
real length: 10

---

The Array from the Chrome Dev tool console:

```
(11) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
1: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
2: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
3: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
4: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
5: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
6: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
7: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
8: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
9: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
10: {b_id: "3759", start_date: "2019-06-01", end_date: "2019-06-30", amount: "1800", platform_id_fk: "1", …}
11: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
12: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
13: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
14: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
15: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
16: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
17: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
18: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
19: {amount: "1800", b_id: "3759", campaignCount: 0, campaigns: 1, company_id_fk: "596", …}
length: 20
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I'm trying to iterate through this array afterwards, and of course the count is now off. Why does it say 10/11 instead of 20?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking!

Comment: Please take the good habit to provide a runnable snippet, it will be easier for everyone to get what you mean.

Comment: There's probably more code involved. Nobody can help you if it's not available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome (and Firefox) dev tools logs at the time you call `console.log()`. For objects, it logs a "summary version" of the object. However, when you expand the logged object, the contents of the expanded version will show the contents of the object *at the time you expanded it*.

In short, at the time you logged it, it *was* 11. But at the time you expanded the log entry, it's already 20. Between the time of the logging and you expanding it, some code probably added 9 more items.

Here's a simple demo. (View in the actual browser console because SO snippets serializes the output for display):

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3]

// This will show 3
console.log('length: ', array.length)

// This will show 3 items
console.log('serialized contents', JSON.stringify(array)) 

// This will show 3 items unexpanded, and is 3 at the time it was logged.
// But this will show 12 upon expand
console.log('unserialized contents', array) 

// Pop in more items
array.push(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
```

A way around this is to use `JSON.stringify()` on your object. Serialize the object into a string, and log that string instead. Alternatively, use dev tools breakpoints to debug your code instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it. I was logging a bunch of debugging info and I was chasing the wrong thing, now that I understand the length issue.